# Is there a name for a total order with a zero element?

Tags: terminology, order-theory

Is there a name for a total order equipped with a zero/bottom element?  (And not necessarily a unit/top element.)

Comment: "Total order with a bottom element" works well :)

Comment: a ray? I've seen "long ray", etc.

Comment: Incidentally is bounded linear total order a name for an order with a top and bottom element?